# Como ter acesso ao consoles do PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, windows

Comprei faz pouco tempo [esse livro](http://www.novateceditora.com.br/livros/postgre/) e tenho seguido as orientações de como efetuar a instalação do PostgreSQL para o sistema operacional Windows:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Consigo fazer todas as alterações possíveis no ambiente interativo, porém quero ter acesso ao modulo de consoles como estou acostumado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso de orientação em relação a isso.

Quando cliquei direto no executável deu esse erro

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Abra o prompt e digite o caminho do psql que pode pode variar,`c:\program file (86)\postgres<versao>\bin` e digite `psql`

Comment: ele gerou um erro que disse que não foi encontrado mesmo eu ter clicado direto no arquivo executável. O que fazer agora?

Comment: @wladyband não executou pelo console?

Comment: executei também e deu o mesmo erro. mas ele existe no caminho indicado.

Answer (score 3):

Você precisa chamar o psql pelo prompt caso contrario  uma tela preta vai aparecer e sumir.

Para não digitar esse caminho longo crie uma variável de ambiente no windows e adicione o caminho do executavel assim o psql ficará disponivel no prompt sem precisar estar na pasta do postgres.

1 - Click com o botão direito em (meu)computador> propriedades > configurações avançadas

2 - Na aba avançado  click em variáveis de ambiente, na guia `variáveis do sistema` click em novo.

[image: propriedades do sistema]

3 - click em `novo` de o nome de `pg_home` e passe o caminho da pasta bin do postgres.

4 - Ainda na guia `variáveis do sistema` procure por `path` click em editar coloque o cursor no final e digite: `;%pg_home%`. O ponto e virgular é o separador de paths no windows.
5 - Abra um novo prompt e digite `psql` deve funcionar.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No prompt digite:

```
psql -U usuario -d database
```

Depois informe a senha do usuario e digite as consultas que precisar.

[Documentação com os parâmetros do psql](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/app-psql.html)

Comment: não deu certo, pois ele até abril, porém na momento em que o usuário precisa digitar a senha ele falha como se a senha estivesse errada.